# Icon and TextInput are not showing in the same line

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have put an icon with the text box but its not showing in a same line,there is problem in alignment.I have tried many solutions . I am using flex Box.Any help would be appreciated.I set parent view to column and set child view in which icon and text box is going to show to row to align it in the same row but its not aligning it proper.i don't knows where the problem is occurring.

```
import {
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <View>
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
        source={require("../assets/bg_image.png")}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image source={require("../assets/ic_logo.png")} />
          <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>Welcome to SMACC</Text>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">
            <View style={styles.loginInfo}>
              <View style={styles.inputField}>
                <Text>User Name</Text>
                <View style={styles.inputText}>
                  <AntDesign style={styles.icon} name="user" />
                  <TextInput placeholder="Enter User Name Here" />
                </View>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  borderBottomColor: "#999999",
                  borderBottomWidth: 1
                  // marginTop: 12.5
                }}
              />

              <View style={styles.inputField}>
                <Text>Password</Text>
                <View style={styles.inputText}>
                  <Feather style={styles.icon} name="lock" />
                  <TextInput placeholder="Enter Password Here" />
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.loginButton}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.forgetPasswordLink}>Foget Password ?</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  },
  welcomeText: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: "Roboto-Medium"
  },
  loginInfo: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    height: 165,
    width: 253
  },
  inputField: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 20,
    //fontSize: 10,
    color: "#999999",
    fontFamily: "Roboto-Medium"
  },
  inputText: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    //flex:0.5,
    //marginLeft: 20,

    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#000000",
    fontFamily: "Roboto-Medium"
  },
  loginButton: {
    flex: 0.6,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#1968B3",
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 5
  },
  loginButtonText: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    fontFamily: "Roboto-Medium",
    fontSize: 12
  },
  forgetPasswordLink: {
    paddingTop: 10,
    fontFamily: "Roboto-Medium",
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#333333"
  },
  icon: {
    paddingRight: 5
    //paddingTop:7
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for the same

Comment: i dont have account there

Comment: You can create one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as inputText style

```
inputText: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    alignItems:'center',
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#000000',
    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
  },
```

feel free for doubts..

Answer (score 2):

Can you try adding display: 'flex' to the css and see if that works?

```
inputText: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: "row",
    //flex:0.5,
    //marginLeft: 20,

    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#000000",
    fontFamily: "Roboto-Medium"
  }
```